# Boot sequences in Windows XP

Tags: windows, boot

In Windows XP SP3, 
do the windows services start before the userinit portion of the registry is executed?

I am wondering as my windows service rewrites the userinit entry when the service starts, but by doing so, it does not appear that the userinit is being executed.

Comment: This document describes the boot process from in exhausting detail however I am not sure if it will answer your question.  http://faculty.stritch.edu/jmsklar/581/docs/Class%201/The%20PC%20Boot%20Process.pdf and here is another resource http://stoicjoker.com/thebootprocess.html however neither of these seem to answer your question.

Comment: Here is additional information on the startup process with some additional details and links from Microsoft http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457123.aspx

Comment: I would not be surprised if any changes to the userinit entry in the Registry would need to be modified and then Windows XP restarted in order for the modification to be effective.  Windows XP may read in the registry information during the beginning of the boot process so that any changes to the registry are not seen until the next time it boots.

Comment: Richard, thank you for the links, they really helped out.   As to the question about making a mod to the registry...  The process i am working is in regards to the auto admin login process in XP.  I need to make changes to the the auto admin right before a system restart is issued, then, when the system is rebooted by the windows service, those values need to be removed.  when the service is started, the values are removed.  the problem is, the service starts and wipes the values in the userinit registry area before the OS kicks in...  crazy race condition.   but thank you!

Comment: I had a problem with terminal startup with an application that was automatically started with an automatic login with Windows XP.  The application, a point of sale, had a race condition with the SQL Server service coming up later than the application which meant that the application was issuing an error due to inability to connect to the SQL Server instance.  We ended up providing a way to set a timer that when the application started, it counted down before continuing initialization providing time for SQL Server service to come up.  My impression is there is a lot of concurrency during boot.

Comment: Richard - you are correct, all the items seem to be spinning up at once...   but i set the service with a dependecy on network services, and that seems to be allowing the service to start up ok.

Answer (score 0):

The services begin before the userinit line is executed in the registry.